# SSRS load report even if cascading parameter is empty

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, expression

I have cascading parameters like: `Year` > `Company` After choosing `Year` value, `Company` parameters are refreshed.

So for example If I choose `2016`, but at this year no data, `Company` parameter is empty (no values) and report says that parameter can't be blank (I've checked "Allow blank values """, but It not working with multivalued parameters) See image below:

[image: blank parameter]

[image: error cant be blank]

How can I load report with message like: *"Sorry, there is no data"*? Or provide any default value for `Company` parameter if there is no other values? Have you any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make your Year parameter data-driven, from the same table as your companies. Make a new dataset like the one below, and use it as the available values for your Year parameter.

```
SELECT DISTINCT year  
FROM companies
WHERE report_relevant = 'Yes'  
ORDER BY 1
```

This limits the users to only pick years where valid companies exist. As soon as a 2016 company is added to your data, the report will automatically include 2016 as a Year parameter option.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm already using this solution, but It not helping for me in this case, for reallity it's more complex, I provided simplified sample. There are `Year` and `Month` parameters...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `UNION` to add an extra row of data to your parameter, but `Count()` your valid companies so the extra row is only included when no other companies would be.

```
SELECT company_id, company_name
FROM companies
WHERE year = @Year
UNION
SELECT '-1', 'No companies in ' + @Year
WHERE (SELECT Count(company_id) FROM companies WHERE YEAR = @Year) = 0
```